# How to reply to "Moon ladings were faked"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I was presented with this statement by one of my friends a few hours ago.

I truly believe in NASA and the moon landings. Therefore, soon we were in a debate and he was telling me some stupid proofs faking the moon landings, some of which I could explain him scientifically. But there were some which I couldn't, because I don't have enough knowledge about it.

My point to come to meta, is to propose a community wiki (or maybe some alternative)  which will include the arguments against the landings and correct scientific explanation. This will be a single destination for all those who have confusion whether these landings were real. What do you think?

Comment: The community here beat you to it. :) Fortunately, this means the requested community wiki already exists!

Comment: Here is the community wiki, by the way: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/how-do-we-know-the-apollo-moon-landings-are-real

Comment: If your friend raised points not addressed there that you wish to address, bring them up on the meta post that is marked as a duplicate of this one, and somebody can add an answer to the community wiki addressing those points if they desire.

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks a lot! I am pretty sure I will find the answer in that thread, because he was raising questions from a YouTube video. Thanks again:)

Comment: Also, try the skeptics stack exchange [e.g has man walked on the moon](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/has-man-walked-on-the-moon/)

Comment: @JCRM Thanks! This helped a lot!