# How to determine when a question should or should not be duped to "...Moon landings are real?"

Tags: discussion, faq

I'm a little confused. I was under the impression that questions which attempted to raise conspiracy theories or challenge facts related to the Apollo Moon landings might be marked as duplicate to "our canonical question and answer regarding moon hoax conspiracy theories" [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/12102), and yet while the recent question [How much cgi would be needed to fake Apollo](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29752/12102) seems to fall squarely in this category, an individual answer challenging the question's premise was posted and the the question was closed as "off-topic".

Could someone help clarify for me how to determine when a question should or should not be duped to "...Moon landings are real?" Do I misunderstand the situation?

For reference see also the following meta questions and their answers:

- [What shall our canonical question and answer regarding moon hoax conspiracy theories be?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1011/12102)
- [The answer to the question about Moon landing hoax theories](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023/12102)
- [Does the community spend too much time on debunking conspiracy theories?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1002/12102)
- [How to reply to “Moon ladings were faked”? [duplicate]](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1041/12102)

As an aside, I'd marked it as duplicate, but the hold message currently shows my user name as part of the "off-topic" vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it probably should have been marked as a duplicate, but that's a new thing and not everybody reads meta.

Strictly speaking, the question was off topic, it was asking about the requirements for faking the material, and as such should have been asked somewhere that knows about 3d rendering algorithms.

Of course, it is most likely the **intent** of the question was flerfy.